# Messy JSON response,gives my trouble

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have been trying all everything that given JSON response,and use it in Android.

```
[{
    "id": "001",
    "firstName": "Mark",
    "lastName": "Mason",
    "role": "CEO",
    "profileImageURL": "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png"
}, {
    "teamName": "iOS",
    "members": [{
        "id": "002",
        "firstName": "Olly",
        "lastName": "Berry",
        "role": "iOS Team Lead",
        "profileImageURL": "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png",
        "teamLead": true
    }, {
        "id": "003",
        "firstName": "James",
        "lastName": "Frost",
        "role": "iOS Developer",
        "profileImageURL": "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png"
    }, {
        "id": "004",
        "firstName": "Liam",
        "lastName": "Nichols",
        "role": "iOS Developer",
        "profileImageURL": "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png"
    }, {
        "id": "005",
        "firstName": "Chris",
        "lastName": "Watson",
        "role": "iOS Developer",
        "profileImageURL": "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png"
    }, {
        "id": "006",
        "firstName": "Richard",
        "lastName": "Turton",
        "role": "iOS Developer",
        "profileImageURL": "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png"
    }, {
        "id": "007",
        "firstName": "Matt",
        "lastName": "Colliss",
        "role": "iOS Developer",
        "profileImageURL": "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png"
    }, {
        "id": "008",
        "firstName": "David",
        "lastName": "Gibson",
        "role": "iOS Developer",
        "profileImageURL": "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png"
    }, {
        "id": "009",
        "firstName": "Tom",
        "lastName": "Guy",
        "role": "iOS Developer",
        "profileImageURL": "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png"
    }, {
        "id": "010",
        "firstName": "Rich",
        "lastName": "Hodgkins",
        "role": "iOS Developer",
        "profileImageURL": "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png"
    }]
}, {
    "teamName": "Android",
    "members": [{
        "id": "011",
        "firstName": "David",
        "lastName": "Branton",
        "role": "Android Team Lead",
        "profileImageURL": "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png",
        "teamLead": true
    }, {
        "id": "012",
        "firstName": "Dre",
        "lastName": "Pilipczuk",
        "role": "Android Developer",
        "profileImageURL": "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png"
    }, {
        "id": "013",
        "firstName": "Ray",
        "lastName": "Britton",
        "role": "Android Developer",
        "profileImageURL": "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png"
    }, {
        "id": "014",
        "firstName": "Charly",
        "lastName": "Murillo",
        "role": "Android Developer",
        "profileImageURL": "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png"
    }]
}, {
    "teamName": "Web",
    "members": [{
        "id": "015",
        "firstName": "Ryan",
        "lastName": "French",
        "role": "Web Team Lead",
        "profileImageURL": "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png",
        "teamLead": true
    }, {
        "id": "016",
        "firstName": "James",
        "lastName": "Ward",
        "role": "Web Developer",
        "profileImageURL": "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png"
    }, {
        "id": "018",
        "firstName": "Adam",
        "lastName": "Smith",
        "role": "Web Developer",
        "profileImageURL": "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png"
    }, {
        "id": "019",
        "firstName": "Leonard",
        "lastName": "Da Costa",
        "role": "Web Developer",
        "profileImageURL": "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png"
    }]
}, {
    "teamName": "Design",
    "members": [{
        "id": "020",
        "firstName": "Hannah",
        "lastName": "Tempest",
        "role": "Design Team Lead",
        "profileImageURL": "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png",
        "teamLead": true
    }, {
        "id": "021",
        "firstName": "Ellis",
        "lastName": "Reed",
        "role": "Designer",
        "profileImageURL": "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png"
    }, {
        "id": "022",
        "firstName": "Pete",
        "lastName": "Horsham",
        "role": "Designer",
        "profileImageURL": "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png"
    }, {
        "id": "023",
        "firstName": "Hemel",
        "lastName": "Dave",
        "role": "Designer",
        "profileImageURL": "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png"
    }, {
        "id": "024",
        "firstName": "Hannah",
        "lastName": "Corke",
        "role": "Designer",
        "profileImageURL": "http://developers.mub.lu/resources/profilePlaceholder.png"
    }]
}]
```

Basically I want to display in a recyclerview,all people who belong in a team. ie

```
"teamName":"iOS","teamName" : "Android","teamName" : "Android","Web" : "Design"
```

It tried this:

```
   package testing.theo.androidtestproject.fragment;



public class TestingFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String IMAGE_URL =  
"http://developers.mub.lu/resources/";
private ArrayList<Model> modelArrayList;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private MyAdapter myAdapter;

public TestingFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_testing, container, false);

    modelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),modelArrayList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    showTestData();
    return v;


}

public void showTestData()
  {



   // Request a string response from the provided URL.
   final JsonArrayRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URLClass.URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

       @Override
       public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
           Log.d("Theo", response.toString());

           for(int i = 1;i<response.length();i++){


               try {


                   JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);


                       JSONArray teamMembersArray = 
        jsonObject.getJSONArray("members");
                       for(int j=0;j<teamMembersArray.length();j++){
                           Model m = new Model();

                           JSONObject teamObject = teamMembersArray.getJSONObject(i);
                           m.setFirstName(teamObject.getString("firstName"));
                           m.setLastName(teamObject.getString("lastName"));
                           m.setRole(teamObject.getString("role"));
                           modelArrayList.add(m);
                       }



               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

           }


           //modelArrayList.add(m);
           // Update list by notifying the adapter of changes
           myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
   }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
       @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

           //hidePD();
       }
   });
   AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);

 }

 }
```

Now I get the same name for every member.:(

Comment: `response.getJSONObject(1);`... Maybe you meant `response.getJSONObject(i);`??

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `gson` library to parse JSON directly into your models? Here's a good example: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few changes: You don't need second loop, no need to check length of object. Reset `Model` in inner loop.

Try this

```
for(int i = 1;i<response.length();i++){ // skipping first object as you said
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
        //m.setRole(jsonObject.getString("teamName"));

        JSONArray teamMembersArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("members");
        for(int j=0;j<teamMembersArray.length();j++){
            JSONObject teamObject = teamMembersArray.getJSONObject(j);
            Model m = new Model(); // reset model in inner loop
            m.setFirstName(teamObject.getString("firstName"));
            m.setLastName(teamObject.getString("lastName"));
            m.setRole(teamObject.getString("role"));
            modelArrayList.add(m);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't this put all people from all teams in the same list?

Comment: modelArrayList.add(m); m is not recongized!

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah it would. Thats what OP want.

Comment: The way I interpretted was a list of people **per** team

Comment: @Theo: probably you used code before my last edit. Just move `modelArrayList.add(m);` inside the inner loop

Comment: @cricket_007: As per OP "*I want to display in a recyclerview,all people who belong in a team*", so I assume he wants only one list.

Comment: I tried this but this was messing this up....Every team member is read multiple times as the list filed inside 3 loops.

Comment: @Theo: Didn't get your last comment. Could you explain?

Comment: `JSONObject teamObject = teamMembersArray.getJSONObject(i);` you should use `j` instead of `i` there

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler: Copy-paste is worst. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Instead of showing "firstName": "Olly", "lastName": "Berry" one time in the recyclerview,it is showed many times.

Comment: Yeah something was wrong. update my code. `JSONObject teamObject = teamMembersArray.getJSONObject(j);`. Had `i` instead of `j` by mistake.

Comment: But now I want to highlight each team leader.

Comment: Add new property in `Model` which would hold a boolean. Set that boolean in the inner loop. In your adapter's `getView` method check for that boolean. If its true, highlight it.

Comment: I added this in my inner loop.   m.setTeamLead(teamObject.getBoolean("teamLead")); But now it shows only the people who are team leaders.

Comment: I use recycleview. not listview:)

Answer (score 0):

Skip the first element starting the loop at 1.
I also changed your loops to use the right variable, let me know if it works:

```
 @Override
 public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
     Log.d("Theo", response.toString());

     for(int i = 1;i<response.length();i++){
     // i = 1 skips the first element

         try {
             JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
             JSONArray teamMembersArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("members");

             for(int j=0;j<teamMembersArray.length();j++){
                 Model m = new Model();
                 JSONObject teamObject = teamMembersArray.getJSONObject(j);
                 m.setFirstName(teamObject.getString("firstName"));
                 m.setLastName(teamObject.getString("lastName"));
                 m.setRole(teamObject.getString("role"));
                 modelArrayList.add(m);
             }
         } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
}
```